# Asterisk / FreePBX: How to differentiate incoming calls?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I have an FreePBX/asterisk server setup with two incoming trunk lines with different DIDs, e.g., 555-1111 and 555-2222. However, the lines represent two different entities operated from the same location, so the staff needs to know which line a call is coming in on.

Is there any way to display the line number calls are coming in on for staff to see? I'm using FreePBX 14 and the Cisco SPA504g phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a couple ways you can do this, but a quick and easy way would be to create a different SIP user for the first two lines on the phone and have calls to trunk A ring the first SIP user and calls for trunk B ring the second SIP user.  The remaining two lines would still get used for roll-over calls though.

You can also change the caller ID info being passed to your phones, we used to handle this to insert the type of call was coming through (B.TECH: ###-###-####, R.TECH: ###-###-####) etc.  You can Set(CALLERID(num)=TRUNKA:${CALLERID(num)}) to add a prefix CID.